# Typhoon Dependency Injection and Swift 3: Appdelegate isn't AnyObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, migration, typhoon

This code works with Typhoon Dependency Injection library (Obj-C) in Swift 2.3 but doesn't in Swift 3:

**AppDelegate:**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var rootViewController: RootViewController?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = self.rootViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
    ...
}
```

**Application Assembly:**

```
    public class ApplicationAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {

        public dynamic func config() -> AnyObject {
            return TyphoonDefinition.withConfigName("Configuration.plist")
        }

        public dynamic func appDelegate() -> AnyObject {
            return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AppDelegate.self) {
                (definition) in

                definition!.injectProperty(#selector(ApplicationAssembly.rootViewController), with: self.rootViewController())
            }
        }
 ...
}
```

However the following error is displayed in ApplicationAssembly for any Swift 3 file expected to return 'AnyObject':
*"No 'withClass' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject'*

Might anyone have an insight into the incompatibility of the Obj-c Typhoon code base with Swift 3?

[Screen capture of error line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkEjx.png)

Comment: could you try with explicit cast

Comment: Explicit cast doesn't seem compatible: 
 `public dynamic func mainUIController() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(MainUIViewController.self) as! AnyObject {
            (definition) in
 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You may want to switch the return type from `AnyObject` to `Any`.**

The `withClass` function returns an id type in Objective-C, [see the source code](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/blob/59b0cde8ef10c6de333c532c0f6229465d89c818/Source/Definition/TyphoonBlockDefinition.h):

```
+ (id)withClass:(Class)clazz block:(TyphoonBlockDefinitionInitializerBlock)block;
```

The `id` type used to be mapped to `AnyObject` in Swift 2, but in Swift 3 it's mapped to `Any` for increased flexibility. [You can read more about this change here.](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39)